# Encoding a decimal number within a range using bitmask

Tags: scala, bit-manipulation, bitmask

I have a usecase to encode number within range of -5.5 to +5.5 using a bitmask of 9 bits, and then apply predefined offset on it. After going through online tutorials, I come up with following approach using Scala:

So I first find the resolution as:

```
val res = 5.5/255
```

Then for an input value v:

```
val minValue = -5.5
val bin = if (v >= minValue) (v/res+(255+1)) else 0
val x = if (bin > 510) 511L else bin.toLong
```

Finally:

```
val MASK = 0x1FF
(x & MASK) << OFFSET)
```

Is this good enough approach?

Comment: Are you wondering, is this good enough from general algorithmic point of view or you wondering Scala specific details? It looks ok as for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem I see is that your code doesn't anticipate change. What if the span changes from -5.5<-->5.5 to maybe -5.5<-->6.1? What if some masks are 9 bits but others need 10?

```
def encode(v:Double, floor:Double, ceiling:Double, bits:Byte) :Long = {
  assert(floor < ceiling, "impossible span")
  assert(v >= floor && v <= ceiling, s"$v: out of bounds")
  val quantum = (ceiling - floor)/math.pow(2,bits)
  ((v - floor)/quantum).toLong
}
```

And you'll need to retrieve the values.

```
def decode(v:Long, floor:Double, ceiling:Double, bits:Byte) :Double = {
  assert(floor < ceiling, "impossible span")
  val quantum = (ceiling - floor)/math.pow(2,bits)
  v*quantum - ceiling
}
```

Which also helps when testing the code.

```
decode(encode(-4.487, -5.5, 5.5, 9)
                    , -5.5, 5.5, 9)  //res0: Double = -4.490234375

decode(encode(2.211, -5.5, 5.5, 9)
                   , -5.5, 5.5, 9)  //res1: Double = 2.19140625
```